# How to mock all layer of application in test method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, xunit.net

I am trying to perform Unit Testing my ASP.NET Core WebAPI with XUnit Project. I am using 3-Layer Architecture where every layer is in different class library project and dependencies ware resolved with dependency injection. Everything is working fine. But when I want to perform unit test I got stuck with mocking of logic layer & data layer. When I run the test I got this error:

> Message: System.ArgumentException : Constructor arguments cannot be passed for interface mocks.

My Mock Object generates in this class:

```
public static class MockObjects
{
    public static  Mock<UserManager<TUser>> GetUserManagerMock<TUser>() where TUser : IdentityUser
    {
        return new Mock<UserManager<TUser>>(
            new Mock<IUserStore<TUser>>().Object,
            new Mock<IOptions<IdentityOptions>>().Object,
            new Mock<IPasswordHasher<TUser>>().Object,
            new IUserValidator<TUser>[0],
            new IPasswordValidator<TUser>[0],
            new Mock<ILookupNormalizer>().Object,
            new Mock<IdentityErrorDescriber>().Object,
            new Mock<IServiceProvider>().Object,
            new Mock<ILogger<UserManager<TUser>>>().Object);
    }

    public static Mock<SignInManager<TUser>> GetSignInManagerMock<TUser>() where TUser : IdentityUser
    {
        return new Mock<SignInManager<TUser>>(
            GetUserManagerMock<TUser>().Object,
            new Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>().Object,
            new Mock<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>>().Object,
            new Mock<IOptions<IdentityOptions>>().Object,
            new Mock<ILogger<SignInManager<TUser>>>().Object,
            new Mock<IAuthenticationSchemeProvider>().Object
            );
    }

    public static Mock<RoleManager<TIdentityRole>> GetRoleManagerMock<TIdentityRole>() where TIdentityRole : IdentityRole
    {
        return new Mock<RoleManager<TIdentityRole>>(
            new Mock<IRoleStore<TIdentityRole>>().Object,
            new IRoleValidator<TIdentityRole>[0],
            new Mock<ILookupNormalizer>().Object,
            new Mock<IdentityErrorDescriber>().Object,
            new Mock<ILogger<RoleManager<TIdentityRole>>>().Object);
    }

    public static Mock<ApplicationDbContext> GetDbContextMock()
    {
        return new Mock<ApplicationDbContext>(new DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>());
    }

    public static Mock<TRepository> GetRepositoryMock<TRepository>() where TRepository : class
    {
        return new Mock<TRepository>(GetDbContextMock().Object);
    }

    public static Mock<ISmsService> GetSmsServiceMock()
    {
        return new Mock<ISmsService>(GetRepositoryMock<SmsRepository>().Object);
    }

    public static Mock<IEmailService> GetEmailServiceMock()
    {
        return new Mock<IEmailService>(GetRepositoryMock<EmailRepository>().Object);
    }

    public static Mock<IProfileService> GetProfileServiceMock()
    {
        return new Mock<IProfileService>(GetRepositoryMock<ProfileRepository>().Object);
    }

    public static Mock<IAccountService> GetAccountServiceMock()
    {
        return new Mock<IAccountService>(
            GetUserManagerMock<ApplicationUser>().Object,
            GetSignInManagerMock<ApplicationUser>().Object,
            GetSmsServiceMock().Object,
            GetEmailServiceMock().Object,
            new Mock<IConfiguration>().Object,
            GetProfileServiceMock().Object
            );
    }
}
```

I implemented this class following this blog post:
https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2019/september/unit-testing-repositories-in-aspnet-core-with-xunit-and-moq/

My Test Method:

```
[Fact]
public async Task RegisterSimpleTest()
{
    // Arrange
    var mockService = MockObjects.GetAccountServiceMock().Object;
    var controller = new AccountController(mockService);
    var data = new EmailRegisterViewModel()
    {
        Email = "a@a.a",
        Password = "123456",
        ConfirmPassword = "123456"
    };
    // Act
    var result = await controller.Register(data) as ObjectResult;

    // Assert
    Assert.NotNull(result);
    Assert.Equal(200, result.StatusCode);
}
```

And Controller Action which I want to test:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody]EmailRegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var errors = ModelStateExtention.GetModelErrors(ModelState);
        return BadRequest(errors);
    }
    var user = new ApplicationUser()
    {
        UserName = model.Email,
        Email = model.Email
    };

    var result = await _accountService.EmailRegisterAsync(user, model.Password);
    return StatusResultExtension<ActionMessage>.GetStatusResult(result);
}
```

How can I perform Unit Test? What's the wrong I am doing?

Comment: Controller actions should be integration tested. Reserve unit testing for things like your account service.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to pass arguments to a `mock` which doesn't work.

If you want to pass a `mock` of `IAccountService` to your `Controller` in the unit test you could do the following:

```
[Fact]
    public async Task RegisterSimpleTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        var mockService = new Mock<IAccountService>();
        mockService.Setup(mock => mock.EmailRegisterAsync( // all you need to mock goes here)

        var controller = new AccountController(mockService.Object);
        var data = new EmailRegisterViewModel()
        {
            Email = "a@a.a",
            Password = "123456",
            ConfirmPassword = "123456"
        };
        // Act
        var result = await controller.Register(data) as ObjectResult;

        // Assert
        Assert.NotNull(result);
        Assert.Equal(200, result.StatusCode);
    }
```

Consult the [quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) for info on how to `mock` behaviour.

Also, I would advise *against* setting up your `mock`s in one class and using that everywhere. You need the flexibility to change behaviour of your `mock`s *per test*. If you find setup cumbersome you could look into [AutoFixture.AutoMoq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.AutoMoq) which lets you setup only the dependencies you need to specify behaviour for in a specific test.